# How to convert decimal number into 64 bit binary float number?

Tags: c++

I need to convert decimal number into 64 bit binary float value.
If you know any algorithm or anything about it then please help.

Comment: what datatype do you have the decimal number in? string? int? sprinkle_decimal? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

```
double num = lexical_cast<double>(decimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a decimal stored inside a string, [atof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012.aspx) would be a standard solution to convert that to a `double` value (which is a 64-bit floating point number on the x86 architecture).

```
std::string s = "0.4";
double convertedValue = atof(s.c_str());
```

Or similar for C strings:

```
const char *s = "0.4";
double convertedValue = atof(s);
```

But if you mean integer number by "decimal number", then just write

```
int yourNumber = 100;
double convertedValue = yourNumber;
```

and the value will automatically be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Value casting from a string to double can be implemented by boost::lexical_cast.
Type casting from int to double is a part of C++:

```
double d = (double)i;
```

It was already mentioned in the previous replies.

If you are interested to know how this casting is implemented, you may refer the sources of the C standard library your compiler is using given that the sources are provided and no floating point co-processor is used for this purpose. Many embedded target compilers do this work "manually" if no floating point co-processor is available.

For the binary format description, please see Victor's reply

Answer (score -2):

```
Decimal decimalNumber = 1234;
Float binaryFloatValue = decimalNumber;
```

Comment: Then i'll leave it to someone else to translate the types into the appropriate C

Comment: C++ doesn't _have_ a decimal type. I'm not sure about C, but that's not the question either.

Comment: "C++ doesn't have a decimal type", which points back to the original question.

Comment: Which seems like a long-winded way of not answering the question at all.